# .NET Building Process - Github/Git and Dependent Projects

Tags: .net, git, msbuild, build-process, nant

I'm currently using Github/Git for two .NET solutions. The first solution is a library of common .NET code for all projects at my company, the second solution is a ASP.NET MVC Web Application.

What does a proper Nant or MSBuild file look like for cloning first repo, build it, clone second repo, add assemblies from first solution to the second? I plan on using Jenkins as my build server. I'm unclear of which parts are handled by the build server and which by the build file. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a build process set up for your company library that puts the compiled binaries into a shared location.  For example a shared network drive, or (preferably) a private NuGet repository if you're using Visual Studio.

Then you add a reference to the assembly/NuGet package in your other projects.  Personally, I'm a big fan of the NuGet route.

The benefit of using NuGet is that you don't *have* to use the new version as soon as it is released (although it is easy to upgrade).

Comment: You mean you leave upgrading the binary up to the developer? Is there a simple way to choose "upgrade" in the GUI NuGet Package Manager? Guess I have just always noticed something as installed or not.

Comment: Yes, so if for example we release update 1.1 to out common library and we're releasing a critical fix to the client project then it is preferable to leave the common library reference as 1.0 to reduce testing time.  Upgrading the package is done by the NuGet command line inside visual studio.

Comment: You can also use the package GUI it seems

Answer (score 1):

use submodules to link the two. You will be able to clone recursively and have all that you need for your build to work.

Comment: +1 - didn't know that was a feature. But I know this is going to confuse the heck out of the developers I work with. This does offer a lot of power. With the current work I am doing I'm always going to want the latest and greatest version of the "framework". It seems like this would be more useful if you wanted to freeze the framework at certain commits from within the main project. Will take it for a test drive tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: you can also investigate `git slave` which automates commands across submodules. It's a separate project I have yet to try.